# Delete bookmark folder from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

For some unknown reason one bookmark folder gets copied 1000+ times (not exactly sure sure how many).

I need some way to delete this.

Tried deleting one by one but after 30-40 times I'm hopeless. How can I get ride of this?

[image]

Comment: Export your bookmarks, edit the resulting file in a text editor, thus allowing you to select hundreds of lines otherwise you’ll probably end up need a bookmark manager addon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Chrome, then press Ctrl+shift+o.
Select the first folder you want to delete.
Use shift and click to select the list of folders.
Finally right-click the selected group and click delete.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :)